# php flushing stdout/stderr

Tags: php, stdout, stderr

I have a php script which runs on my ubunutu server. this script runs in an infinite loop running queries and gathering statistics... it is a monitor for some other services. Every 60 seconds the stats that are gathered are dumped as a json object to a .js file. The .js file is monitored elsewhere and is unimportant for the purpose of my question.

When I run my script I redirect both stdout and stderr to a log file.
For the most part there is no output either standard or error and so the log will remain empty.

Obviously though on occasion there will be output. The problem I experienced last night was the script failed for some reason and the log file ended up filling up the whole partition and messed with the stability of the server.

What I have done.. or tried to do is add in a simple check that every 60 seconds (when the stats are dumped) the script checks the size of the log file.. and if it is greater than X mb in size, basically empties the file and allow logging to continue. With the intention being that if the script does experience a problem again, the log file wont fill up the whole partition.

I can successfully detect the log file size, I can successfully clear it when it reaches my set size, but then the next time there is either a STDOUT or STDERR write, all the previous data is dumped in one go.

Any assistance with this would be greatly appreciated.

---

Calling script by:

```
php checker.php &> log
```

but have tried

```
php checker.php > log 2>&1
```

and also redirecting the streams at the start of the script

```
close(STDOUT);
fclose(STDERR);
$STDOUT = fopen($LOG_FILE_LOCATION, 'wb');
$STDERR = fopen($LOG_FILE_LOCATION, 'wb');
```

each way produces the same output.

Code clearing log file

```
function CheckLogFilesize($file)
{
    global $LOG_FILE_LOCATION;
    global $MAX_LOG_SIZE_MB;
    $max_log_size_bytes = $MAX_LOG_SIZE_MB * 1024 * 1024;

    $size = exec('stat -c %s ' . $file);

    // If log file size is too large.. reset it.
    if (intval($size) > $max_log_size_bytes)
    {
        flush();

        // Clear the log
        $fp = fopen($file, 'w');
        fwrite($fp, '');
        fclose($fp);
    }
}
```

Thanks

Comment: What do you mean by it is dumped in one go?  Also could you post your code here?

Comment: basically im sitting watching the file size of the log file.
i watch it reach the max file size ive set. say 100bytes.
i watch it reset back to zero. and then the next write that is made to the empty file should be 10bytes.. sets the size of the log file to 110bytes.

Am emptying the file:
  $fp = fopen($file, 'w');
  fwrite($fp, '');
  fclose($fp);

Comment: Try PHP's `flush();` function

Comment: thanks but no luck. placed the flush() just prior to the clearing of the log file. log file still reset to 0 and then does a large jump in file size at next write.

one thing to note is when i open the log file in vi after it has been emptied and then re-written to by the script.
the first line of the file consists of ^@ character repeated. following on from my explanation above.. the ^@ characters take up 100bytes of the file (the data that was cleared) and then the log continues on in normal readable text for the subsequent 10bytes. (hope that made sense)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**EDIT**

Figured it out:

```
function get_log_size() {
    clearstatcache();
    return filesize("/tmp/log.log");
}

foreach (range(1, 1000000) as $interval) {
    echo $interval . "\n";
    usleep(10000);
    if ($interval % 50 == 0) {
        fwrite(STDERR, "mod 50 fail test");
    }
    $size = get_log_size();
    echo $size . " bytes\n";
    if ($size > 100) {
        $file = "/tmp/log.log";
        $fp = fopen($file, 'w');
        fclose($fp);
        print "Truncated\n";
    }

}
```

Started with

```
php test.php >> /tmp/log.log 2>&1
```

Note the **>>** instead of **>**.  You have to use append mode

Example output of `tail -f /tmp/log.log`:

```
λ ~/ tail -f /tmp/log.log

1
2 bytes
2
12 bytes
3
23 bytes
4
34 bytes
5
45 bytes
6
56 bytes
7
67 bytes
8
78 bytes
9
89 bytes
10
101 bytes
Truncated
11
13 bytes
12
25 bytes
13
37 bytes
14
49 bytes
15
61 bytes
16
73 bytes
17
85 bytes
18
97 bytes
19
109 bytes
Truncated
20
13 bytes
21
25 bytes
22
37 bytes
23
49 bytes
24
61 bytes
25
73 bytes
26
85 bytes
27
97 bytes
28
109 bytes
Truncated
```

Comment: have added some sample code at the top.
just tried clearing the log the same way as you have there (with a separate shell) and it did NOT work. same issue occured.

Comment: just tried repeating the test you performed and it did NOT work on my machine. this would suggest a setting somewhere :s  
this was my output when i over wrote the log file very quickly after running it...  
  
^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@9  
10  
11  
12  
13

Comment: sorry.. new to stackoverflow and can't seem to get line breaks working in comments :s

Comment: @poinda: that was my mistake.  I was running it with `>>`, not `>` and was retyping here.  SO is a good example of where copy/paste pays off.

Comment: @poinda: also note that you do not need to run a separate shell process with `stat -c $filename`, you can just `clearstatcache` and use the `filesize` method.

Comment: Thanks very much for your assistance! Issue identified! And thanks for the pointer re filesize method. I was initially using it but wasn't aware of clearstatcache and hence was getting a cached repsonce and it wasnt working as desired. Cheers!

Answer (score 1):

If I had to do such thing, I would detect the logfile size and if it is larger than the threshold, move the file to another filename (e.g. old-log.txt). In that case you will have maximum of 2 logfiles with total size of 2 times threshold.

Advantage is that you still have some old log entries just after the threshold was reached. If you just clear the file, you will see that you try to find info in an empty file

EDIT:

Take a look at the ob_* commands in PHP. They may help you clearing the buffer(s)

[ob_start()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.ob-start.php) In the comments you can find some more info about stdout

```
...
ob_start();
// keep writing log until done
ob_end_clean(); // or use ob_end_flush();
```

some pseudo code...

Comment: I get what you are saying and will probably try and implement something like that. in the short term though I suspect the same issue will occur. I could copy the log file that exists to log2. then reset log to empty. but again on the next write it would be full again.

Comment: seems some kind of buffer not being cleared. see updated answer

Comment: have looked at the option presented be ob.. only problem is doesnt work for stderr

Answer (score 1):

If you're redirecting `stdout` into a log file, you can even try to `unlink()` that file but it won't work, because your `stdout` is still connected to it.

One way is to clear the log file before you start the process and have the process stop when the file goes beyond a certain size. Then just let your script run inside a shell script loop (that only terminates when the process exist code = 0, i.e. no errors); when the script stops, it will get launched again immediately.

Normally, daemons open their own log files, so you can send them a `HUP` signal to reopen their log files, thus avoiding a complete restart.

Comment: If I dont have any luck I think I'll go down this path. Thanks for suggestion